# How do I hide a control based on a DropDownBox's status? C#

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I would like to hide a Text Box based on the items selected in the comboBox.

This is my code:

```
private void Banner_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Banner.Text.Equals("Yes"))
    {
        this.BannerText.Visible = true;
        this.label12.Visible = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        this.BannerText.Visible = false;
        this.label12.Visible = false; 
    }
}
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I want the `BannerText` and `label12` to be visible when "Yes" is selected in the combo box. This should only appear once "Yes" has been selected. Does anyone have the code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try fixing your brackets.

```
if (Banner.Text == "Yes")
{
    BannerText.Show();
    label12.Show();
}
else 
{
    BannerText.Hide();
    label12.Hide();
}
```

Currently, with that `else` statement floating out there by itself, your code won't compile.

Comment: Hardly the reason, it wouldn't compile with the else and no brackets. Maybe, the text is not "Yes"?

Comment: @user2158786, do the following. First, make comparison selected index based, not text based (who knows what *exactly* you have in this dropdown). Second, debug to this line and watch what happens.

Comment: I only have "Yes" and "No" options in the combo box

Comment: That is great. Please at least tell us what was the problem.